# Qt 5.6: Full Windows 10 support

Tags: qt, windows-10-universal, qt5.6

I was looking at the Qt 5.6 feature list, and it claims 'Full Windows 10 support'. Now I'm wondering, does this mean that ALL Qt features are supported on Windows 10 by the release of Qt 5.6? I'm asking this because I really want to use QtBluetooth on Windows 10, but Qt is not clear about the support of that on Windows 10.

Can someone clarify things up?

Comment: https://wiki.qt.io/New_Features_in_Qt_5.6, is quite clear. Full Windows 10 support, which naturally implies that all Qt features are supported, including Bluetooth. The schedule for 5.6 release is in December, so I would suggest to wait until then and test it yourself on release :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In [Qt 5.5](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtbluetooth-index.html) Qt Bluetooth was supported for the following platforms:

Android, iOS, Linux (BlueZ 4.x/5.x) and OS X

Then in 2015 Qt developers discussed Bluetooth for Windows, see [blog](https://blog.qt.io/blog/2015/06/29/qt-bluetooth-and-its-state-of-the-union/)

> Hopefully, we can close the gap towards the last major platform which is not yet supported. A WinRT port is being planned for Qt 5.6

But in Qt 5.6 there are no new features related to Qt Bluetooth and in [tracker](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-31674) we see that:

WinRT (classic and Low Energy) is scheduled for Qt 5.7.

So this is not a question of Win10 support, I guess Qt Bluetooth will remain for the same platforms in Qt 5.6 and will be ported for Windows later.

Comment: WinRT Bluetooth support was shifted to 5.8.